# Google Play Services force closing

Tags: google-play-services, crashes

I have a Samsung Galaxy Pocket. Google Play Services has always worked for years on my phone. But a few weeks ago, I noticed my phone was 'force close vibrating' constantly.

After looking and watching my 'running services', I noticed Google Play Services kept restarting straight after the force close vibration.
I uninstalled Google Play Services and it stopped. (but why was it doing it in the first place?)

I reset my phone to the factory, installed my usual apps, and installed Google Play Services again. And straight away it did it again.

Is there a way to fix this? As I play a few games, etc. on my phone, some games it says it needs Google Play Services to run it.

Comment: By "gps" I assume you mean Google Play Services, not the driver for your phone's Global Positioning System (GPS)? I would suggest installing Google Play Services **first** after another factory reset and see what happens. Then start adding apps back one at a time. The problem may be with one of your "usual apps," not with Google Play Services.

Comment: Between the lines I read: Your device is rooted, its bootloader unlocked, and you're using a custom ROM (otherwise you couldn't uninstall Play Services, and hadn't to install it manually). If I'm correct with that, and a factory-reset didn't bother you: Wipe all storage, re-flash your custom ROM and GApps, then check if it's working *before you install anything else.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to factory reset the phone? If not just try it. Because there are some apps which make the Google play services to force stop.

**Even then if it will not be able to revive then report to Google**

Comment: Read the entire question, please. A factory reset was performed.

Comment: @JoeSewell well he said that he installed his usual apps again. So what will be the impact of even factory reset. It must be one of his apps that makes it to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much for yur time! :-) Yes sorry l ment Google Play Services. Yes l installed that first after a reset and it still did the force close vibration. Even if l turn vibration off for the phone it still does it.

Comment: I even said that report it to Google. They take these things seriously. So they will definitely reply you, chick.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you uninstall all the cleaning apps such as Clean Master, CM Cleaner, etc.

I had faced the same sort of problem with my Wynk app and don't forget to restart or reboot your mobile after doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the phone (Galaxy Pocket) but the fact that the version of Google Play Services is not supported by the phone. Uninstalling Google Play Services stops the vibration, try it.